# Include does not work on index file

Tags: php, html, include

I have a little problem with including files. I have two pages where i use exactly the same starting 10 rows.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <?php include "../~13097377/include/head.html"; ?>
    </head>
    <body id="body" >
    <div style="background-color: #E0ECF8; min-height: 100%;">
    <div style="position:fixed; background-color: #E0ECF8;">
    <?php include "../~13097377/include/slideshow.html"; ?>
    <?php include "../~13097377/include/menu.html"; ?>
    <div style="padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;">
```

http://eduweb.hhs.nl/~13097377/index.php 
http://eduweb.hhs.nl/~13097377/contact/contact.php

The contact page reacts normal but the index page gives a lot of errors like "failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www"
Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a relative path, `../etc...` in your include, which means the path being checked is RELATIVE to the location of the script you're running the include directive from.

That means, assuming your document root is `/var/www/site/html`

```
/var/www/site/html/index.php           -> /var/www/site/~13097377/include/head.html
/var/www/site/html/contact/contact.php -> /var/www/site/html/~13097377/include/head.html
```

Unless you have a `~13097377` directory in BOTH your doc_root and doc_root/contact directories, this is why you get your errors. You're telling PHP to look for your file in a place that doesn't exist.

Comment: Oke, I understand. But why does it work on the contact page but not on index?

Answer (score 1):

Relative paths are not going to work when your files are in different levels of directories. You can use an absolute path, relative to the root of the web-server:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/~13097377/include/slideshow.html"; ?>
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/~13097377/include/menu.html"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all instances of `?php include` to `<?php include`.

All PHP code should be between `<?php` opening and `?>` closing tags.

Once you fix the syntax errors, check on your include paths.  They are probably relative but may not be depending on webserver and PHP configuration.